# Configure correct htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

i use htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule detalhe/(.*) detalhe.php?id=$1
```

i want redirect:
https://example.com/detalhe.php?ID=31&URL=lorem-to-lorem

to:
https://example.com/31/lorem-to-lorem.html

any ideias to help?

Answer (score 0):

You may use an additional rule to handle additional URI segment:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/detalhe\.php\?ID=(\d+)&URL=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.+)$ detalhe.php?ID=$1&URL=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^detalhe/(.*) detalhe.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, but nothing happened. Url as same.

Comment: i use https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to validate rules and not success too.

Comment: Check updated answer and test it on your Apache not on that website

Comment: Wow! works. But another links in page agregatte te ID: https://example.com/31/index.php.  Its possible a condition to apply this rule only in detalhe.php ?